# JavaScript addEventListener with Event and Binding a variable

Tags: javascript, scope, arguments, actionlistener

I'm busy trying to dynamically assign functions to certain buttons and I've run into a strange problem that I'm absolutely stumped with.

I have the following simple HTML for demonstration purposes

```
<div id="butts">
   <button>BUTT 01</button>
   <button>BUTT 02</button>
</div>
```

Now I am assigning functions to these buttons using JavaScript with the following loop (including the event)

```
var butts = $("#butts").find("button");
for(var cnt = 0; cnt < butts.length; cnt ++) {

   // get button description just for testing
   var buttonDesc = $(butts[cnt]).text();

   // EVENT
   butts[cnt].addEventListener (
      "click", function(event) {
         funcEvent(event)
      }
   );

}
```

Calling a very simple test function to verify that it is working

```
function funcEvent(event) {
   console.log("funcEvent");
   console.log(event);
}
```

This is working fine but I also need to pass a variable to the function which I would normally do as follows

```
var butts = $("#butts").find("button");
for(var cnt = 0; cnt < butts.length; cnt ++) {

   // get button description just for testing
   var buttonDesc = $(butts[cnt]).text();

   // BIND
   butts[cnt].addEventListener (
      "click", funcBind.bind(this, buttonDesc)
   );

}
```

Another very simple test function

```
function funcBind(buttonDesc) {
   console.log("funcBind");
   console.log(buttonDesc);
}
```

Separately they both work just fine but I am struggling to pass the event argument in the bind function

I am trying to combine the two so that I can call a single function that can receive both the event and the argument

---

### *UPDATE*

This seems to be a possible fix although I do not understand how to be honest

With the same loop

```
var butts = $("#butts").find("button");
for(var cnt = 0; cnt < butts.length; cnt ++) {

   // get button description just for testing
   // using var did not work (always last element of array)
   // var buttonDesc = $(butts[cnt]).text();
   let buttonDesc = $(butts[cnt]).text();

   // EVENT
   butts[cnt].addEventListener (
      "click", function(event) {
         funcEventBind(event, buttonDesc);
      }
   );

}
```

Calling a very simple test function to verify that it is working

```
function funcBindEvent(event, buttonDesc) {
   console.log("funcEvent");
   console.log(event);
   console.log(buttonDesc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a closure so that the even handler callback contain the context. You can do that by using `forEach` like this

```
butts.forEach(function(bt) {
  var buttonDesc = $(bt).text();

   // BIND
   bt.addEventListener (
      "click", function(event){
          funcBind(event, buttonDesc)
       }
   );
})
```

Comment: I did try this but the buttonDesc variable is always the last description in the loop so I don't think it is binding correctly

Comment: @Trent Are you using `forEach` function (instead of for loop) as I described in answer?

Comment: No, it's telling me butts.forEach is not a function

Comment: @Trent You have added `var butts = $("#butts").find("button");` line before `forEach`, right?

Comment: I did something very similar but with butts.each() but the thing that fixed it (and I have no idea why) was I changed var buttonDesc to let buttonDesc, I will update my question with this possible fix

Comment: I will still mark this as the correct answer because it was hugely helpful in pinning down the bug

Comment: @Trent `let` works because it is block scoped unlike `var`. I did not suggest the `let` solution because it is not a generally considered a good practice to create function inside the loop.

Comment: You're right, I changed it drastically to work without without loops and instead I'm just applying the function to an array of objects. It seems better aligned with best practices but is a bit unrelated to this question so I'm not going to post it. Thank you so much for your help though